# How do I use pd.date_range to filter rows?

Tags: pandas

I am unable to use the date_range function to filter dates in my selection. Basically my question is how do I use the date_range function instead of manually entering the range?

I am currently doing this:

```
 newdf = newdf.loc['2019/12/1':'2019/12/5']
```

But I would prefer to work with the date_range function somehow:

```
newdf.loc[dateRange]
```

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv("EURCHF.csv", skipinitialspace=True) 
newdf = df.loc[:,'Date':'Low']
dateRange = pd.date_range(start ='2019/12/12', end ='2019/12/20')
newdf = newdf.set_index(['Date'])
newdf = newdf.loc['2019/12/1':'2019/12/5']
newdf
#newdf.loc[dateRange]
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    Date         Time        Open      High    Low
0   2019/6/27   10:00:00    1.11237 1.11254 1.11126
1   2019/6/27   14:00:00    1.11161 1.11375 1.10998
2   2019/6/27   18:00:00    1.11008 1.11056 1.10981
3   2019/6/27   22:00:00    1.11028 1.11072 1.10927
4   2019/6/28   02:00:00    1.10939 1.10967 1.10833
```

Comment: I like your current solution of passing date strings with `:` slice notation into `df.loc[]`. How else would you tell either `loc` or `date_range` which dates to select?

Comment: Im not sure I am still new to this. If it looks good to you then I guess it is as good as it gets for now. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isin` method as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': np.random.rand(32)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2019/01/01', '2019/02/01', freq='D' )) 


df_filtered = df[df.index.isin(pd.date_range('2019/01/01', '2019/01/04', freq='D'))]
df_filtered

                a
2019-01-01  0.179021
2019-01-02  0.224770
2019-01-03  0.185422
2019-01-04  0.067197
```

However I am pretty confident that `df.loc[start_date:end_date]` is the pythonic way to go for.